# append a span at the cursor(caret) location in the contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the following code in which i want to append span to contentEditable div of ID #display. now in #display if changed the cursor position using mouse, and if i want to append span to the #display, how to append that after the caret position.

```
$(".operators").click(function(){
        var selectedOperator = $(this).html();
        var addSpan= "<span>" + selectedOperator + "</span>"
        $("#display").append(addSpan);
    });
```

please guide me according to the above program. help will be thanked.

Comment: Use $("#display").wrapInner(addSpan);

Comment: and the sentence that ends with `?` is?

Answer (score -1):

Variable will not hold any DOM elements, you should add DOM while appending.

```
$(".operators").click(function(){
    var selectedOperator = $(this).html();
    $("#display").append('<span>'+ selectedOperator +'</span>');
});
```

[Check working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/PratapRockers/wjcpnzey/)

Comment: i am not asking about that, thats ok. the thing is how to append span at the cursor location in the div when click out of the div